# How to do pagination like book page flip left to right and right to left with sqlite db and json data

Tags: json, database, flutter, sqlite

**I want to display data from Sqlite database and json in pagination format that page turns in book from right to left and left to right** i need same feel like a book that i am reading a book

i tried package Flip_widget package but unable to handle such operations please help me out how i can do this